# set codeigniter session using jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, session-variables

i am using jquery ajax function to set codeigniter session, but unable to set and get the response back!

```
$.ajax({
        url: site_url+'controller/cart/'+id,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

while on the cart function side,

```
public function cart($id) {
    if($this->session->userdata('cart') == "" ) {
        $cart = array();
    } else {
        $cart = $this->session->userdata('cart');
    }

    if (!in_array($id, $cart)) {
        array_push($cart, $id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('cart', $cart);
    }

    echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('cart'));
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
success: function(result) {
     alert(result);
}
```

result is the object. For fully look it, try this code:

```
success: function(result) {
     console.log(result);
}
```

End see output in development console of your browser

Comment: Are you shur for request work right? Ypu may check your ajax request and response by development tools (firebug in FF or developer console in chrome)

Comment: Yes i am using firebug, request is working fine, but response is empty, dont know where i made mistake!

Comment: var_dump $this->session->userdata('cart') before json_encode end se in response, may be some mistake before

Answer (score 0):

Try using a response variable in [your url]?json_response. then in your php make the http[url]?json_response = to your data and echo it out to be received by your ajax request in one shot. You should set your ajax.dataType to only accept json. Then you should be able to use the php json encoded data within ajax.success like so:

```
success: function (data){
 if(window.console){
  console.log(data);
 }
}
```

or in your ajax.complete:

```
complete: function (response){
 if(window.console){
  console.log(response.responseText);
 }
}
```